# JQuery/Javascript not working on Mobile Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I have a website that gets links from the Bing API for a certain search query. It if the page url has the words 'mazda' in it, scrab the website for these certain parameters and display them.

This works perfectly on Desktop.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5swkSFB.png]

However on mobile, this section does not even pop up on Mobile

[image: http://i.imgur.com/f2Vl1O6.png]

This is what the HTML looks like

```
<h2 id="theirLocation" style="text-align: center; text-decoration: underline;"></h2>
<ul id="theirLocationList" style="text-align: center;">
</ul>

<h2 id="otherInfo" style="text-align: center; text-decoration: underline;"></h2>
<ul id="otherInfoLinks" style="text-align: center;">
</ul>

<a href='#unSortedLinks' id="unSortedLinks" style="text-align: center; display: block; font-weight: bold;"></a>
<ul id="unsortedLinksList" style="text-align: center; display: none;">
</ul>
```

As you can see, there is no innertext/innerhtml in the beginning

And this is the Javascript

```
function getProfileInfo(profileURL) {
    $.get(
        profileURL,
        function(response) {
            var carBrandText = profileURL.toLowerCase().match(/(audi|Subaru|Lexus|Porsche|bmw|mazda|buick|toyota|kia|honda|hyundai|volvo|mini|mercedes|volkswagen|ford|lincoln|scion|acura|chevrolet|nissan|infiniti|gmc|cadillac|dodge|chrysler|rover|mitsubishi|jeep|fiat)/i);
            if (carBrandText) {
                console.log("HERE");
                var getCarModelYear = response.match(/Model(\sYear)?.{0,10}(\d{2,4})/i);
                if (getCarModelYear) {
                    $('#otherInfo').text('Other Information');
                    $('#otherInfoLinks').append('<li>Car Year: ' + getCarModelYear[2] + '</li>');
                    console.log(getCarModelYear[2]);
                }
                var getCarModelManufacturer = response.match(/Manufacturer.{0,10}(audi|Subaru|Lexus|Porsche|bmw|mazda|buick|toyota|kia|honda|hyundai|volvo|mini|mercedes|volkswagen|ford|lincoln|scion|acura|chevrolet|nissan|infiniti|gmc|cadillac|dodge|chrysler|rover|mitsubishi|jeep|fiat)/i);
                if (getCarModelManufacturer) {
                    $('#otherInfo').text('Other Information');
                    $('#otherInfoLinks').append('<li>Car Manufacturer: ' + getCarModelManufacturer[1] + '</li>');
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: where does `profileUrl` and `response` come from?

Comment: @dipanda I updated the post

Comment: I am wondering whether you are encountering a CORS error - trying to load data from another domain. Maybe on the desktop works somehow due to your setup... which browsers are you using? Try to chain a `.fail()` (or `.error()` if you're using jQuery < 1.8) to your get request, to see if there are some errors (see the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) )

Comment: @dipanda I plugged my phone in and checked the console out while I did it and I got no strange errors

Comment: You have to understand where your code breaks. Try to put some `console.log()` or `alert()` in your callback to see what gets executed correctly, try to log the output of carBrandText, getCarModelYear  and getCarModelManufacturer. I assume that by saying "plugged my phone in" you mean you are remote-inspecting your mobile browser? Are you using Chrome on Android?

Comment: I put a console.log And yeah, that's exactly what I meant by plugged my phone in. And I am using Chrome on Android, and I tested it on Safari for iPhone as well. @dipanda I updated the OP with where the console.logs are. Update - I realized that the mazda link doesn't even appear

Comment: @dipanda I realized what the issue is, I have an ajax jquery that is supposed to call a function that gets the carModelManufacturer and year. For some reason, that function isn't being called when on Mobile